# How to see jobs saved on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I remember (or maybe I am imagining) that there was a way to see the jobs I saved on Stack Overflow (a functionality similar to the one provided on LinkedIn.)

But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to see or visit the jobs I saved.

Any suggestions? I'm sure it's someone on the user's profile, but I can't find it. There has to be a way (otherwise why provide a "save" button)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find your saved searches and saved (favorited) jobs in the right hand side bar. When you save a search, you should see a pop up confirming the search was saved.

[image: saved search]

Comment: @Des, the question is asking about **saved jobs**, *not saved *searches**, so the answer is: they are listed as favorites, and you can see them all by clicking in ***View all favorite jobs*** (after clicking first on Developer Jobs). IMHO, this is an UI bug, either the button should be called **Add to Favorites**, or the list should be called **Saved Jobs**. How is it this still here since 2011? (A saved job is not necessarily a Favorite)

Comment: This is ridiculous! The UI designer who did this should have studied Jakob Nielsen's usability principles better. Very soft color, which is the same color of the link/button `View all favorite jobs`, with no bullet points, no odd/even background differences, no row separators, only a slight differ in the line-height to distinguish between two jobs and two rows of the same job, AND the aforementioned naming idiosyncrasy. Guys, ok the flat design, but this is the first time in over six years I needed to search how to do something on SO. Thumbs down.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore - I least I can't find it.

Answer (score 5):

Took me a bit to find it, but on the Jobs page, do a page search "Ctrl-F" search for, "View all favorite jobs"

Answer (score 1):

The [View all favorite jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?f=True) link is hidden until you starred at least 5 jobs.